# How can I Add Google Tag Manager to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google, google-tag-manager

I want to add (GTM) google tag manager in my Magento 2 store, but without installing any extension.

Please help me out that how I can add CTM manually.

Answer (score 2):

**METHOD TO ADD GOOGLE TAG MANAGER TO MAGENTO 2 STORE**

In Magento 2, you can easily add the Google Tag Manager without any need for a third-party extension.

To add Google Tag Manager to your Magento 2 store, all you need to do is add your unique Google Tag Manager code to your theme.

The Google Tag Manager code is divided into two parts – Script & NoScript.

You need to put these code snippets into two separate phtml template head and body files as shown below.

```
// YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml

<script>..</script> <!-- GTM code -->

// YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml

<noscript>..</noscript> <!-- GTM code -->

Now, we also need to load these files correspondingly through the default default.xml file.

<!-- YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml -->

<referenceContainer name="head.additional">

<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />

</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">

<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />

</referenceContainer>
```

Your Google Tag Manager code is finally added and now you can set up your Google Analytics for monitoring and reporting of your Magento 2 store.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Magento Admin Panel and move to **Content > Design > Configuration > Edit the Store View > Other Settings> HTML Head**.

Paste the code you got from GTM for the  tag here.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add Google Tag Manager in Magento 2 without third-party extensions. All you need is to add the GTM code to your active theme. **The GTM code is divided into two parts: script and noscript.**

> You need to put the GTM snippet into these two phtml templates for head and body:

**YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml**

```
<script>..</script> <!-- GTM code -->
```

**YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml**

```
<noscript>..</noscript> <!-- GTM code -->
```

To load the files correspondingly you should use the default .xml file:

**YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

***NOTE: You must run the deploy command after adding the above files***

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use some ready-made Magento 2 GTM extension, because if you just add Google Tag Manager (GTM) code to the HTML head, how would you like to integrate Google Analytics (GA), Google E-commerce Tracking, or Google Remarketing?

There are a lot of free and paid modules for that. So all you need to do is to install one:

1. [Magento 2 GTM Extension](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html) by **WeltPixel** - I used it a lot in the past, but **it doesn't work with Google Analytics 4**, so I recommend using the next one.
2. [Magento 2 Google Tag Manager Extension](https://magefan.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager) by **Magefan** - **the best option** for now as for me. It is also available on [GitHub - https://magefan.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager](https://github.com/magefan/module-google-tag-manager).
3. [Magento 2 GTM Extension](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager) by **Magepal** - another option, if you don't like 2 previous ones.

So run these commands to get the GTM extension:

```
composer require magefan/module-google-tag-manager
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After that navigate to your Magento 2 admin panel > Stores > Configuration > Magefan Extensions > Google Tag Manager and Analytics > [Configure and enable the GTM](https://magefan.com/blog/add-google-tag-manager-to-magento-2).